# Scalaアプリに対して、クラスの依存関係をテストする方法を教えてください

Tags: scala, テスト, アーキテクチャ

Scalaで書かれたアプリケーションに対して、アーキテクチャをきれいに保ちたいと考えています。
そこで、複数のクラスの間での依存関係をアーキテクチャ上のレイヤごとに制約して、
ビルド時にこれを違反する場合には検出出来るようにしたいと思っています。

JavaではJDependという、クラス間依存関係に対するテストを書くためのツールがあります。
実際にアーキテクチャをシンプルに保つために使われているようです。

JDependはJavaVM向けに作られたソフトウェアのようなので
おそらくScalaでも上手くやればsbt設定などから
使えるのではないかと思うのですが、そういったドキュメントを見かけません。

Scalaでも似たようなことはできないでしょうか。
またはJDependをScalaでも利用できないでしょうか。
設定方法やツールを教えていただきたいです。

(他の情報として、もしかしたら https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732370/how-to-detect-dependencies-on-java-classes-in-scala-sources が全く同じ質問のようにも思うのですが、情けないことに英語を正確な形で理解することが出来ないでいます。)

Comment: この質問はした後で、微妙な問題( https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2848/%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%8C%E5%88%86%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8C%E3%81%B0%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%8C%E8%87%AA%E6%98%8E%E3%81%8B%E3%82%82%E3%81%97%E3%82%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F ) があるかもなあと思ったので、METAの方に質問を投げておきました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

自己解決したので記録します。

このような用途でScalaに対して使えるフレームワークとしてArchUnitがあります。
https://www.archunit.org/

ArchUnitは基本的にはJava向けに作られていますが、ScalaやKotlinでも利用可能です。
特にScalaに適用する場合、適当なテストフレームワーク(以下のサンプルではscalatest)の中で呼び出して使う形になります。

```
package com.example.archunit

import org.scalatest._

import com.tngtech.archunit.core.domain.JavaClasses
import com.tngtech.archunit.core.importer.ClassFileImporter
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.ArchRule
import com.tngtech.archunit.lang.syntax.ArchRuleDefinition.classes


/** アーキテクチャについてのテスト(適応度関数)
 */
class ArchTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  private val packageClasses: JavaClasses = new ClassFileImporter().importPackages(
    // 自分自身のパッケージのクラスを検査対象にする
    "com.example.archunit",
    // 他にも依存しているパッケージを記述してよい
  )

  it should "各モジュールはルートパッケージに依存していない" in {
    val rule = classes()
      .that()
      .resideInAPackage(".")
      .should()
      .onlyHaveDependentClassesThat()
      .resideInAPackage(".")
    rule.check(packageClasses)
  }
}
```

とすると、(依存関係等の)アーキテクチャ自体についての検査をScalaでも実現できます。
メソッドチェイン内の内容については、公式の最新サンプル等を参照にするとよいでしょう。

Answer (score 1):

自分では試してないんですが、これで出来そうじゃないですか？
https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/sculpt-dependency-graph-extraction-for-scala/1507

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらは残念ながら不適合だったので、この後調べたものを自己回答しておきます